# Load images from tableLayout android

Tags: java, android

I have five rows  imageView, but this code load only 4 rows? why?

**Java code**

```
tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
for (int i = 0; i < tl.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View v = tl.getChildAt(i);
    if (v instanceof TableRow) {

        for (int j = 0; j < ((TableRow) v).getChildCount(); j++) {
            View innerView = ((TableRow) v).getChildAt(j);
            if (innerView instanceof ImageView) {
                imageList.add((ImageView) innerView);
                idList.add(innerView.getId());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Layout**

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="275dp"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView25"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_column="6"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView13"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView12"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView14"
                android:layout_column="6"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_column="6"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView18"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView17"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView16"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView15"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView19"
                android:layout_column="6"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView23"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView22"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView21"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView20"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView24"
                android:layout_column="6"
                android:src="@drawable/blog_dp_5058985_7848593_tr_woda" />

        </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: please post the xml or the code which creates the tableLayout

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3q5iRURi   paste because i can't  add  code  here.

Comment: I've tested your code, it works perfectly fine, all of the 25 ImageViews were added to imageList.

Comment: Why do you use nestedScrollingEnabled tag ? Are there any modification in your code which can effect the tableLayout?

Comment: So, where  I can have problem ?

Comment: In other parts of your code. I tried the above codes in an empty project and it worked as it should.

Comment: I created new project and  now   there not see  R.id.tableLayout.. why?

Comment: try to clean or rebuild the project

Comment: Yea, it woking! Thanks, but I have one more question. Can you show me how I can comparing two  imageView?  eg  image.get(1).getdrawable()==image.get(2).getdrawable()? 

I have to check if  images  it same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can comparing two imageView? eg
> image.get(1).getdrawable()==image.get(2).getdrawable()?

No, by this way it just comparing whether they are the same object or not. In this case this will be false. But, if you want to compare the images of the imageviews, then you should get theirs bitmap then use [sameAs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#sameAs(android.graphics.Bitmap)) method.

```
        //comapre objects returns false
        Log.i("EQ", (imageList.get(0).getDrawable().equals(imageList.get(1).getDrawable())) + "");
        Log.i("EQ", imageList.get(0).getDrawable().toString()); //android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@89c323c
        Log.i("EQ", imageList.get(1).getDrawable().toString()); //android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@837dbc5

        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable0 = ((BitmapDrawable) imageList.get(0).getDrawable());
        Bitmap bitmap0 = bitmapDrawable0 .getBitmap();

        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable1 = ((BitmapDrawable) imageList.get(1).getDrawable());
        Bitmap bitmap1 = bitmapDrawable1 .getBitmap();

        //comapre the image returns true
        Log.i("EQ2", Boolean.toString(bitmap0.sameAs(bitmap1)));
```

Where i called toString() it shows that, they are not the same object, although they are holding the same image as sameAs indicating.

Note:
instead of equals() method, "==" operator would do the same, there is no difference